# How to inject logger in an extended class (XClass) in Typo3?

Tags: php, logging, typo3

I want to extend the \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\NewRecordController in Typo3 and log something to the logging system. The Logging section in Typo3 help says that I should instantiate the logger by injecting LoggerInterface to the constructor of my class. So my code is something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Project\Xclass;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;


class NewRecordController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\NewRecordController
{
    private LoggerInterface $logger;
    
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected function renderNewRecordControls(ServerRequestInterface $request): void
    {
        $this->logger->warning('test');
    }
}
```

When I run the code (add a new record in Typo3 BE) I get **ArgumentCountError** error.

I tried setting *public:true* in *services.yaml* provided in the third link below, but now lock.

How can I fix this?

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Logger/Index.html

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html#

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html

PS.

It seems that the problem exists even in the case I'm not extending an interface. To test this, I tried to implement the event listener 'AfterFileAddedEvent', and I still get the same error. My code is mentioned below:

ManuscriptAdded.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Project\EventListener;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Event\AfterFileAddedEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ManuscriptAdded
{
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(LogerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __invoke(AfterFileAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->logger->critical('testtest');
    }
}

?>
```

Services.yaml:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
    
  Vendor\Project\EventListener\ManuscriptAdded:
    tags:
      - name: event.listener
        identifier: 'msAdded'
        event: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Event\AfterFileAddedEvent
```

Comment: isn't the error message perhaps more about the log entries? `$this->logger->log($level, $message, $data);`

Comment: @David I don't think so. The full error is: Too few arguments to function Vendor\Project\Xclass\NewRecordController::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/user/Typo3 Projects/Local/typo3_src-10.4.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 3480 and exactly 1 expected

and it refers directly to _construct function redefinition.

Comment: Mhm, then the dependency injection isn't working probably: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#errors-resulting-from-wrong-configuration you could try it like this: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#method-injection and remove the `__construct`-method

Comment: `__construct` methods in controllers make often problems and are not advised, The controllers are injected by themselves and constructors called at the wrong moments or not at all.

Comment: It looks strange to me. Because the Typo3 documentation says that it is the preferable way since v11. > "For examples of instantiation with LoggerAwareTrait or GeneralUtility::makeInstance(), switch to an older TYPO3 version for this page. Instantiation with dependency injection is now the recommended procedure.". Actually I could make it work with makeInstance(), but I'm afraid it will be deprecated in newer versions, so I'm trying to do it in the best way.

Comment: so what's your thought about `injectMyDependency()`? that doesn't require the `_construct()` method and looks future proof for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TYPO3 v11.5 you may try this:

```
class ManuscriptAdded
{
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Logger */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogManager $logManager
     */
    public function __construct(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogManager $logManager)
    {
        $this->logger = $logManager->getLogger(self::class);
    }

    public function __invoke(AfterFileAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->logger->critical('testtest');
    }
}
```